# Is there a significant difference for updating 1 column or many in a merge operation

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to benchmark different merge scenarios and I was wondering if there is a difference in performance in the following scenarios:

1. Only explicitly updating 1 column

```sql
MERGE INTO customer_account ca
USING recent_transactions t
ON t.customer_id = ca.customer_id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET balance = balance + transaction_value
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (customer_id, first_name, last_name, city, country, balance, currency_code)
  VALUES (t.customer_id, t.first_name, t.last_name, t.city, t.country, t.transaction_value, t.currency_code);
```

2. Defining every column even if it can't change

```sql
MERGE INTO customer_account ca
USING recent_transactions t
ON t.customer_id = ca.customer_id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET
    -- These should never change
    ca.customer_id = t.customer_id,
    ca.first_name = t.first_name,
    ca.last_name = t.last_name,
    ca.city = t.city,
    ca.country = t.country,
    ca.currency_code = t.currency_code,

    -- This can change
    balance = balance + transaction_value
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (customer_id, first_name, last_name, city, country, balance, currency_code)
  VALUES (t.customer_id, t.first_name, t.last_name, t.city, t.country, t.transaction_value, t.currency_code);
```

3. Every column changes in the row

```sql
MERGE INTO customer_account ca
USING recent_transactions t
ON t.customer_id = ca.customer_id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET
    -- These all are new values
    ca.customer_id = t.customer_id,
    ca.first_name = t.first_name,
    ca.last_name = t.last_name,
    ca.city = t.city,
    ca.country = t.country,
    ca.currency_code = t.currency_code,
    balance = balance + transaction_value
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (customer_id, first_name, last_name, city, country, balance, currency_code)
  VALUES (t.customer_id, t.first_name, t.last_name, t.city, t.country, t.transaction_value, t.currency_code);
```

So essentially this is a question of whether it is worth to benchmark these different cases, or is an update the same amount of work regardless of if only 1 column has a new value (ie behind the scenes postgres rewrite the entire row any time any part of the row is updated)

Comment: Intuitively, this is probably not worth worrying about.  If you're using a remote server, the compute time will probably be overwhelmed by the network overhead anyway.

Comment: it can't never be the same, as every value must be overwritten in a file on the disk, but i concur with @TimRoberts that it will not matter comparing with latency

Comment: Because of PostgreSQL's implementation of MVCC, It doesn't matter how many of the columns change value or even if any of them change value, if a row matches the selection crtiteria, then the original row will be marked as inactive and a new row will be written. The inactive row should eventually be removed by the PostgreSQL vacuum process.